# How to select a journal at the intersection of two domains?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, research-undergraduate

My professor has asked me to select a journal to publish the paper I have been working on, which focuses on analysing the performance of NNs, SVMs etc. on existing datasets in the Network Security Domain.

I am a new researcher (just finished by Bachelors), and I'm unsure how to go about selecting a journal; I tried sending the paper to an AI journal, which rejected it suggesting I submit it to a journal closer to the application domain. I do believe the paper lies in the domain of AI/Machine Learning, as it's majorly a performance analysis of datasets and their properties. How would I go about selecting the correct journal, accounting for things like impact factor etc.?

Comment: There are many factors that aids to the selection of a journal or any other publication venue. You are asking us to search stuff for you and such a question is regarded as "shopping" question in academia.SE.

Comment: I'd suggest to rephrase this question so as to make it more broadly applicable beyond the particular intersection you're interested in.

Comment: @Coder I do have a list of journals I think might be suitable. But then again, I thought the first journal selected was suitable too, so I'm looking for advice on how to improve my journal-selection skills.

Comment: @henning I was thinking it might be an interesting topic to discuss, but wasn't sure. I've changed the title now.

Comment: Very odd for a professor to leave this entirely up to you.

Comment: It is the job of the professor to find a suitable journal.

Comment: @mystupid_acct. He's asked me to decide as he is unfamiliar with the one of the domains covered.

Comment: As a first year grad student, you are unfamiliar with BOTH domains.

Comment: @mystupid_acct I know, it's not ideal. Any and all advice would be helpful.